# Is there a way to decrease a value by a percentage and increase others in the same table without selecting 1 by 1

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I need help building a SQL query,I'll post my homework,it's a bit tricky to explain...so you can get a better idea of what's my problem:

Increase the population of the chief town by 1%,representing inhabitants from the municipalities moving to the chief town..
Example:

London city and municipalities(used google translate,sorry if there's some mistakes): 600000 inhabitants

```
London city: 300000 inh.
   Municipality1:50000 inh
   Municipality1:80000 inh
   Municipality1:70000 inh
   Municipality1:100000 inh
```

increase city inh by 2%

```
London city: 306000 inh.
   Municipality1:49000 inh
   Municipality1:78400 inh
   Municipality1:68600 inh
   Municipality1:98000 inh
```

---

My database has this table
tab_municipalities.

```
**Municipality_description**|**Inhabitants**| **Province**
London-------------------------|300k---------| London
Muni1---------------------------|50k-----------| London
Muni2---------------------------|80k-----------| London
Muni3---------------------------|70k-----------| London
Muni4---------------------------|100k---------| London
```

So,is there a way to change the Chief city percentage of inhabitants and changing the Municipalities without selecting them one by one?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
set tab_municipalities update London=(London*1.02);
```

My problem comes here...How do I "spread" the increment of the chief town on every Municipality,decreasing their inhabitants? Sorry if I wrote all this detail but I wanted to be more clear about what I had to do...I need to transfer this query in a java project.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the rule that define how much we should decrease each line ? If you add 8000 to London, do we take 2000 from each other city ? or 5000 from one, and 1000 from each three left ? or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Since London city contains half of the total population in this example we can simply add 2% for the city and remove 2% from all other rows directly (without using some sum that needs to be distributed).

Use a CASE when updating

```
UPDATE tab_municipalities 
SET Inhabitants = CASE WHEN Municipality_description = 'London' THEN Inhabitants * 1.02
                  ELSE Inhabitants * 0.98
                  END
WHERE Province = 'London'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are working along the right lines but thinking too precisely. In SQL you UPDATE the table and SET the column

```
 UPDATE tab_municipalities
 set inhabitants = inhabitants*1.02 
 WHERE province='London' and municipality_description='London'
```

You could then run a second UPDATE to carry out the calculation to reduce the municipalities:-

```
 UPDATE tab_municipalities
 set inhabitants = inhabitants*0.98 
 WHERE province='London' and municipality_description<>'London'
```

Ideally you need to separate the Chief Town from it's members. You could have a separate table for "towns" and then link the municipality via the Town_id. This would make your data a lot clearer as at the moment you have mixed use for the table.

Comment: That would increase the population not only in the city of London but also all of the municipalities (which should have a decrease in population)